# Como eu realizo/funciona a chamada pela url do AJAX?

Tags: javascript, java, html, log, thymeleaf

**Para contextualizar**:

Existe um diretório remoto, `clearing-dit\logs`, que possui uma serie de logs (`portal.log`, `test.log`, ...). Esse diretório, é mapeado para uma pagina HTML, onde todos os seus `.log's` são exibidos. Uma vez que um deles seja clicado, o seu respectivo conteúdo é exibido.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse conteúdo é carregado através da pagina HTML/thymeleaf, que chama o conteúdo de um `log.java`.

```
<p th:utext="${log.content}">Log content</p>
```

Surgiu a necessidade de fazer com que esse conteúdo continue sendo exibido (suas atualizações) a cada 5seg, em tempo real e sem ter que atualizar toda a pagina, somente atualizando onde se encontra o conteúdo. Andei pesquisando e vi que consigo/devo fazer isso através de um AJAX, mas o conceito dele é um tanto vago para mim.

**Minha duvida:**

Como eu realizo/funciona a chamada pela url do AJAX? Eu sei que no AJAX existe dois campos type -> POST/GET e o url -> (?), mas não consigo entender como funciona esse "crossover", pois, em tese, se fosse possível chamar o método que exibe o conteúdo atual:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/log", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String logContent(@Valid Log log, BindingResult bindingResult, Map<String, Object> model) {
        if (log.getInitLine() == 0 && log.getFinalLine() == 0) {
            try {
                fileNumberLines(log);
                log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            log.setContent(getLogContentByRange(0, log.getInitLine(), log.getFinalLine(), logsDir + "/" + log.getFilename()));
        }

        model.put("path", logsDir);
        model.put("log", log);
        model.put("currentPage", "logs");
        model.put("root", root);

        return "log";
    }
```

A cada 5seg, resolveria o problema.

Comment: No seu caso, um simples refresh da página não resolveria?

Comment: A ideia era dar refresh somente no <div> que o conteúdo se encontra, justamente pra evitar que toda a pagina seja atualizada. Não mencionei isso mesmo, vou editar!

Comment: Cara dá uma olhada aqui pra ver se te ajuda http://www.marcelustrojahn.com/2016/10/spring-boot-e-thymeleaf-fragmentos-via-ajax/